# Ler nomes de arquivo txt em C

Tags: c, string, txt

Então basicamente o codigo precisa ler os nomes de um arquivo txt(DEPOIS VOu MANIPULA-LOS) ate ter a palavra 'fim. Nessa parte do código onde ele lê as linhas, ele apenas armazena a 1 string da linha e ignora as que vem depois e depois ele pula a linha para o próximo nome.
**Preciso de ajuda para conseguir ler a linha inteira e armazenar os nomes.**

Essa parte aqui que esta o problema, ela separa a linha em strings, mas ela só esta pegando uma string

```
aux = strtok(frase," ");
```

O arquivo tem esses nomes:

```
Arya Meryn 
Meryn Syrio 
Brienne Stannis 
Ellaria Myrcella 
Jaime Aerys 
Brienne Jaime 
FIM
```

O código não lê o 2 nome das linhas

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    int contador;
    char *aux;
    char frase[1000];
    char *vetor[250];
    char vetor2[200][200];

    FILE *arquivo;
    arquivo = fopen("nomes.txt","r");
    contador = 0;
    do{
        fgets(frase,100,arquivo);
        strlwr(frase);

        aux = strtok(frase," ");
        vetor[contador] = aux;
        strcpy(vetor2[contador],vetor[contador]);

        printf("-->%s\n",vetor[contador]);
        contador ++;

    }while(strcmp(frase,"fim")!=0);
    contador --;
    for(int i =0;i<contador;i++){
        printf(" %s \n",vetor2[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema está na sua interpretação do [`strtok`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/). O que a função faz é navegar token a token ("palavra" a "palavra") sobre o que foi passado. Cada navegação é feita a cada chamada do `strtok`. Significa que se vai dividir em 3 palavras e quer apanhar as 3, tem de ter 3 chamadas ao `strtok`. Por isso isto tipicamente é utilizando com um `while`.

Atente neste troço da [documentação](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/):

> On a first call, the function expects a C string as argument for str, whose first character is used as the starting location to scan for tokens. In subsequent calls, the function expects a null pointer and uses the position right after the end of the last token as the new starting location for scanning.

Traduzindo:

> Na primeira chamada a função expera uma string ao estilo do C como argumento para `str` em que o primeiro carater é usado como inicio do local a percorrer para obter tokens. Nas chamadas seguintes, a função espera um ponteiro nulo e usa a posição a seguir à último token encontrado como posição de partida para achar o próximo.

No seu código se assumirmos que existem 2 nomes separados por um espaço em cada linha, com um espaço no fim como tem no seu exemplo, basta fazer o seguinte:

```
char *nome1, * nome2;
...
do{
    fgets(frase,100,arquivo);
    strlwr(frase);

    nome1 = strtok(frase," "); //le o primeiro nome
    nome2 = strtok(NULL, " "); //le o segundo utilizando NULL na chamada ao strtok
    printf("%s, %s\n", nome1, nome2);

}while(strcmp(frase,"fim")!=0);
```